# Grid footer disappears on browsers other than IE

Tags: html, css

I am displaying a grid in an IFrame on my homepage. The grid uses a CSS file to define design for rows, columns, header & footer.

Below is the image of the grid. In the footer, you can see the page navigation links.

[image]

The problem is that this footer is displayed on IE, but it is invisible in all the other browsers. What changes I need to do in this CSS code:

```
body { font: 0.8em Arial; }

/* Datagrid Table */
table.tbl { width:100%; border: 2px solid #94DEFA; font-size: 0.9em; clear: both; }
table.tbl tr td:first-child { display: none; }

/*td.tbl-header { background: url(/images/head_bg.gif); text-align: center; padding: 3px; font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 2px solid #c3daf9; }*/
td.tbl-header { background-color:#94DEFA; text-align: center; padding: 3px; font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 2px solid #c3daf9; }
tr.tbl-footer {}
table.tbl-footer {display:table-row; font-size: 1em;}
tr.tbl-row {height: 40px}
tr.tbl-row:hover { background: #EBFFFF; cursor: pointer; } /* Old color: #E9E9E9 */
tr.tbl-row-even { background: #F5F9FF; }
tr.tbl-row-odd { background: #FFFFFF; }
tr.tbl-row-highlight:hover { background: lightblue; cursor: pointer; }
td.tbl-nav { background: url(/images/head_bg.gif); height: 20px; border-top: 2px solid #c3daf9; color: #4D4D4D; }
/*td.tbl-nav { background-color:#c3daf9; height: 20px; border-top: 2px solid #c3daf9; color: #4D4D4D; }*/
/*td.tbl-nav { background-color:white; height: 20px; border-top: 2px solid #c3daf9; color: #4D4D4D; }*/
td.tbl-pages { text-align: center; }
td.tbl-row-num { text-align: right; }
td.tbl-cell {}
td.tbl-controls { text-align: center; }
td.tbl-found {}
td.tbl-checkall {}
td.tbl-page { text-align: right; }
td.tbl-noresults { font-weight: bold; color: #9F0000; height: 45px; text-align: center; }
span.tbl-reset { margin: 5px 5px; }
img.tbl-reset-image { margin-right: 5px; border: 0; }
span.tbl-create { margin: 5px 0; }
img.tbl-create-image { margin-right: 5px; border: 0; }
div.tbl-filter-box {}
img.tbl-arrows { border: 0; }
img.tbl-order-image { margin: 0 2px; border: 0; }
img.tbl-filter-image { border: 0; }
img.tbl-control-image { border: 0; }
span.page-selected { color: black; font-weight: bold; }
input.tbl-checkbox {}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see it online, can I get a link? Could be something to do with sizes, because you set the rows to a set height of 40px, not sure.

Comment: I even adjust the sizes, but it is invisible on other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that this code was developed in IE8. If so your best bet would be to start over coding for a standards compliant browser like Firefox or Opera, then apply the custom changes needed to make the IEs look right via conditional comments.